# Using "Theme.of" causes re-builds on the widget

Tags: android, flutter, dart, provider

I use the `Theme.of(context)` to stylize a **box decoration** in the **drawer widget** of my app. But this causes my drawer widget and its parent to rebuild itself a few more times when I toggle the theme switcher (which shows a fade-in/fade-out effect while switching to the light/dark theme) via `Provider.of` on the button press.

Why is this so? Isn't it enough to rebuild the widget one time, or two times at most? It doesn't happen when I use a static color like `Colors.green`. I need to avoid these rebuilds because it may affect the app in the future as the code gets grow. In fact, it's affecting at the moment.

**My app tree is like this:**
- MyApp (StatelessWidget)
--- Provider
----- Consumer
------- MaterialApp
--------- HomeScreen
----------- Scaffold
------------- Drawer <- which is using the `Theme.of(context)` and gets built a few more times unnecessarily when I toggled the theme, and causes the HomeScreen also rebuild itself

Comment: let see few codes... if you setState in a build function it might happen... let see how you toggle the theme

Comment: All of them are stateless widgets. I'm using Provider as I said. Once a button in the drawer clicked, I update the theme thanks to the Provider+Consumer.

Comment: so you change the theme one time and yet it forces multiple rebuilds?

Comment: Exactly. It happens only when I use `Theme.of` to specify the color of the BoxDecoration of the DrawerHeader in the Drawer. If I use a static color like `Colors.green`, it builds only once. Multiple times otherwise (3-4 times). I wonder the reason, if it's normal and should I ignore..

Comment: i just made a quick test and it seems that rebuild is done only once

Comment: If you create a custom widget (say something like "AppDrawer" extending `Drawer`) in a separate file and use Theme.of to stylize a color property in that custom widget, you can see it. It results many builds while the fading effect of the theme switching occurs.

Comment: Have you found a solution, or logged an issue? I seem to have the same issue. I'm not using a custom widget though.

Comment: If I remember correctly, I hadn't found a solution. If you file an issue, please let us know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[An issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/89127) was filed on Flutter's Github repo.

Google employees have confirmed the issue but are not investigating at the moment.

Personally I'm avoiding the static Inherited Widget method `Theme.of(conext)` until this is fixed.

Instead I use a State management solution to hold ThemeData, making it accessible throughout the app.  I refer to it when theme items are needed.